# Does the upgrade-insecure-requests csp header update form actions?

Tags: content-security-policy, upgrade-insecure-requests

Having trouble finding an answer to this. If I set the CSP "upgrade-insecure-requests" header on a page will it upgrade form actions? The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) on the topics say "non-navigational insecure resource requests" are upgraded, but it's not clear if form actions count.

Comment: Form actions will be upgraded, even if they’re cross-origin. See the section of the spec at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-upgrade-insecure-requests/#upgrade-request — *“We will not upgrade cross-origin navigation requests, with the exception of form submissions. Form submissions will be upgraded to mitigate the risk of data leakage via plaintext submissions.”*